# Custom post type query creates blank infinite loop in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

Creating a shortcode that would pull a certain custom post type. Using the_title() for test purposes. The shortcode itself is working fine (echoing an attribute value). Query when used outside a shortcode works fine as well. But when it comes down to querying the post type inside the shortcode, at first, it takes quite a bit of time to load. And when it finaly does, it repeats the shortcode attribute with previously used shortcode many-many times. Title doesn't show. 
So, Let's say I'm using 2 shortcodes on the same page.

Shortcode 1 (the problematic one):

```
[custom-table custom="here we are gonna have a slug"]
```

Shortcode 2:

```
[custom-button width="300px" bg="#29b938" color="#ffffff" padding="25px 35px" text="Start Your Diet" font="25px" weight="bold" style="" url="http://google.com" new-tab="true"]
```

code for shortcode 1

```
function tables_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start();
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'custom'=> 'none'
    ), $atts));
    $tabargs = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'offset'         => 0,   
        'post_type' => 'customtables'

    );

    $tabs = new WP_Query($tabargs);
    if ( have_posts() ) while ($tabs->have_posts()) : $tabs->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo $atts['custom'];
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom-table','tables_shortcode');
```

code for shortcode 2 (works fine on its own)

```
function custom_button($atts) {
    ob_start();

     extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'width' => '200',
            'bg' => '#000',
            'color' => '#fff',
            'padding' => '10px 20px',
            'text' => 'Visit Now',
            'font' => '20px',
            'weight' => '300',
            'style' => 'normal',
            'url' => '#',
            'new-tab'=> 'false'
   ), $atts));

?>

    <div class="inrevbtn">
            <a class="custombtn" href="<?php echo $atts['url'];?>" <?php if ($atts['new-tab'] == 'true') { echo 'target="_blank"'; } ?>>
                 <?php echo $atts['text']; ?>
            </a>

    </div>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom-button', 'custom_button');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a very confusing syntax on your button. Your first href quotation is native, but the second one is being echoed. That makes it really hard to read and parse, even for an IDE. Also, you don't need to use [`extract()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) if you're not going to use the extracted variables (like `$text` instead of `$atts['text']` - Note that variables with a dash will fail to get extracted because `$new-tab` is not a valid variable, but `$new_tab` and `$newtab` are valid, so you should use one of those in your shortcode array instead, if you do want to use `extract()` that is.

In your second shortcode, you're checking if the global query has posts with `have_posts()`, you should be running that method off of your `$tabs` custom WP Query instead.

You've also got a syntax error in your `if`, you're not starting it with a `:` or `{` and thus closing it with a `endif;` or `}` - I presume that this one specifically is the cause of your issue.

Try something like this for your button code:

```
add_shortcode('custom-button', 'custom_button');
function custom_button($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'width'   => '200',
        'bg'      => '#000',
        'color'   => '#fff',
        'padding' => '10px 20px',
        'text'  => 'Visit Now',
        'font'  => '20px',
        'weight'  => '300',
        'style'   => 'normal',
        'url'    => '#',
        'newtab' => false
    ), $atts));

    ob_start();
?>
    <div class="inrevbtn">
        <a class="custombtn" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" <?php echo ($newtab == 'true') ? 'target="_blank"' : ''; ?>>
            <?php echo $text; ?>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And something like this for your table code:

```
add_shortcode('custom-table', 'tables_shortcode');
function tables_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'custom'=> 'none'
    ), $atts));

    ob_start();

    $tabargs = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'offset'         => 0,   
        'post_type'      => 'customtables'
    );

    $tabs = new WP_Query( $tabargs );

    if( $tabs->have_posts() ){
        while( $tabs->have_posts() ) : $tabs->the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo $custom;
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Side note, you may want to clarify your class/id/variable names a bit. `$tabargs` and `$tabs` makes it sound like you're making a tabbed item in the code. There's almost literally zero overhead in changing those to more semantic names like `$table_args` and `$table_query` to help identify at a glance what they are.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! the tables part been fixed. With your edits, the button wouldn't open the link in new tab, but it wasn't the piece damaging the rest of it. So, I left it as is (see updated version). Thanks!

Comment: Well like I had mentioned, you'd need to change to using `new_tab` or `newtab`, in your attributes and your code variables, so your shortcode would need to end with ` [… newtab="true"]` (using the code as I had written), not ` [… new-tab="true"]`. Glad to help!